# Typo3 Extbase: Adding subcategory changes alls subcategories names to number values

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a problem with my extbase extension:
I have a category and a subcategory (1:n), but if I edit my category and add a new subcategory, all my subcategory names will change to numbers, any ideas?

[image: rel1]
[image: rel2]
[image: rel3]

Answer (score 0):

Found what the problem was: in ext_tables.php Region 'sortby' => 'regionenname' caused the error, now I have 'sortby' => 'sorting' again and everything is fine.